# Cargar un fondo en HTML con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

estoy aprendiendo html css y javascript, disculpen si es algo basico.

Estoy queriendo hacer que se cargue una imagen de fondo con javascript haciendo uso del style.background. pero por alguna razon no me esta cargando nada, al parecer el callback esta roto o algo asi

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.backgroundImage = url('gatito.png');
});
```

Les dejo mi trozo de codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posiblemente sea porque `load` no se aplica a elementos `div`. Si lo que deseas es que una vez cargue el contenido se muestre el `background` al `div`, puedes hacerlo con `DOMContentLoaded`.

```
const div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  div.style.backgroundImage = `url(https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png)`;
});
```

Aquí solo indico que cuando cargue todo el `DOM` de todo el documento, llamo al `listener` y ejecuto la función, quien se encarga de colocar el fondo a la etiqueta `div`.

---

Puede que el problema sea ese, o que no puedas visualizar la imagen porque el `div` no tiene un ancho específico para visualizar la imagen. El `div` debe tener estas propiedades:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

En donde:

- `width: 100%`: El **`div`** tendrá un ancho del `100%`.
- `height: 500px`: El **`div`** tendrá un un alto de `500px`.
- `background-repeat: no-repeat`: **La imagen de fondo** no se repetirá.
- `background-size: contain`: **La imagen de fondo** ocupará toda la escala posible, sin  recortarse ni estirarse.

[***Véase más aquí.***](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

---

**Demo:**

```js
const div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  div.style.backgroundImage = `url(https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png)`;
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```